# hGetContents hangs when getting contents utf-8 file

Tags: haskell, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm parsing files from a git repository and, while planning to use the gitlib module for that, I'm getting the file contents using the git executable for now - until I find some tutorial or have time to dive into gitlib's code.

I have a function that essentially run a "git show" for a specific file on a specific commit, and return its contents. Here is a full working example.

```
import System.IO
import System.Process
import System.Exit

main = do
  let commit = Commit { hash = "811e22679008298176d8be24eedc65f9e8c4900b", time = ""}
  fileIO <- showFileIO "/path/to/the/repo" (commit, "/path/to/the/file")
  putStr (show fileIO)

showFileIO :: String -> (Commit, String) -> IO (Commit, String, String)
showFileIO directory (commit, filepath) = do
  (_, Just hout, Just herr, procHandle) <- createProcess $ createCommand command directory
  hSetEncoding hout utf8
  hSetEncoding herr utf8
  exitCode <- waitForProcess procHandle
  stdOut   <- hGetContents hout
  stdErr   <- hGetContents herr
  if exitCode == ExitSuccess
     then return (commit, filepath, stdOut)
     -- Continue in the case of an error.                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     else return (commit, filepath, "")
  where command = "git show " ++ (hash commit) ++ ":" ++ filepath

createCommand :: String -> FilePath -> CreateProcess
createCommand command directory = (shell command){std_out = CreatePipe, std_err = CreatePipe, cwd = Just directory}

-- Where Commit is defined as:                                                                                                                                                                                                               
data Commit = Commit { hash :: String
                     , time :: String
                     } deriving (Show)
```

I was initially getting some errors ("invalid byte sequence") when getting the contents of a php file with mime-type "text/x-php" and charset "utf-8", and that was resolved when I set the encoding of the Handles to utf8. There is another file with mime-type "text/html" that is actually a html.twig file (Twig templating engine) with charset "utf-8". Now the function hangs indefinitely when trying to get the contents of this file. It works fine for other files.

Any ideas what could be wrong? How do I even get to debug in Haskell something that does not give me an error or any info? Are there any debugging tools that could help with that?

Comment: i am not sure how it relates to your question, but I had sometimes problems with the buffering - see https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hSetBuffering maybe it helps

Comment: Can you produce a minimal example?

Comment: It may be that `waitForProcess` is hanging, because you have not yet consumed `stdOut` and `stdErr`. Try calling `waitForProcess` after fully consuming them; this could be done easily with the `BangPatterns` language extension.

Comment: @BenJames I was just writing the same thing. It's also plausible that compiling with `-threaded` might change something...

Comment: @n.m. I have updated the code to a full working example. You would apparently need to change the hash and paths to real ones if you want to test this out.

Comment: @BenJames I am consuming the result in the main. Also, if there was a reason like this, it would either work or not for all files. At the moment it works for all files I have tested apart from the specific one mentioned.

Comment: @krystalcode My point was that it may be consumed too late. It's difficult to predict what will happen with lazy I/O in the Haskell runtime; I have seen code like this work on one Haskell version and not work on another, so it's plausible it may differ between files.

Comment: @BenJames yeah, it seems lazy evaluation was the issue indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something like this: (untested)

```
showFileIO directory (commit, filepath) = do
  (_, Just hout, Just herr, procHandle) <- createProcess $ createCommand command directory
  hSetEncoding hout utf8
  hSetEncoding herr utf8
  stdOut   <- hGetContents hout
  evaluate (length stdOut) -- strictify the above lazy IO
  stdErr   <- hGetContents herr
  evaluate (length stdErr)
  exitCode <- waitForProcess procHandle
  if exitCode == ExitSuccess
    ...
```

Alternatively, use some strict-IO variant of `hGetContents`.

Note that there still is, as far as I can see, some window for deadlock. If the command produces a vast amount of data on stderr, then the command & OS buffers will become full and writes to stderr will block. Since the Haskell consumer now first waits for stdout to be consumed completely, we have a deadlock. Note that this will not be an issue for "short" error messages.

If we want to make it more robust, we need to read from both stdout and stderr at the same time. E.g.

```
showFileIO directory (commit, filepath) = do
  (_, Just hout, Just herr, procHandle) <- createProcess $ createCommand command directory
  hSetEncoding hout utf8
  hSetEncoding herr utf8
  stdOutV <- newEmptyMVar
  stdErrV <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO $ do
    stdOut   <- hGetContents hout
    evaluate (length stdOut)
    putMVar stdOutV stdOut
  forkIO $ fo
    stdErr   <- hGetContents herr
    evaluate (length stdErr)
    putMVar stdErrV stdErr
  stdOut <- takeMVar stdOutV
  stdErr <- takeMVar stdErrV
  exitCode <- waitForProcess procHandle
  if exitCode == ExitSuccess
    ...
```

*Update*. This should also work, and is much simpler.

```
showFileIO directory (commit, filepath) = do
  (_, Just hout, Just herr, procHandle) <- createProcess $ createCommand command directory
  hSetEncoding hout utf8
  hSetEncoding herr utf8
  stdOut   <- hGetContents hout
  stdErr   <- hGetContents herr
  forkIO $ evaluate (length stdOut)
  evaluate (length stdErr)
  exitCode <- waitForProcess procHandle
  if exitCode == ExitSuccess
    ...
```

I wouldn't be surprised if there were some library function doing all of this for you, but I can't remember anything at the moment.

Unrelated: I prefer `proc` to `shell` to construct the `CreateProcess` options. The latter requires careful escaping of filenames (spaces, special characters), while the former simply takes a list of strings parameters.

Comment: Tried evaluating stdOut and stdErr, that seemed to work. Would you know why this is needed for one file, while lazy evaluation works for another file? Exact same code for both ... Is the main function not consuming the IO, therefore triggering evaluation?

Comment: @krystalcode Maybe in the other file the output is small enough so that the program can print it, the OS will store in its own buffers, and then the program can exit. The problem presents itself when the output doesn't fit the OS buffers.

Comment: that should be it. This file is around 1000 lines of code, while others that where quite smaller. Thanks for the thorough response, looking for a library that handles all these sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Note also that there's also a function that lets you hook up standard out and error of the new process to handles of your choice. You could probably just tell it to dump the errors into a file and come back and read that later.